# Is there a way to capture the Google Analytics 4 Measurement ID from the Google data layer?

Tags: google-analytics-4

I've used the following method for getting the Google Universal Analytics Tracking ID from the data layer:
`ga.getAll()[0].get('trackingId')`

I'm wondering if it is possible to get the GA4 Measurement ID in a similar way.

I've been able to access the Measurement ID when exposed by the website data layer in some instances, but have not found a standard method for capturing it.

Answer (score 0):

It took me FOREVER to figure this out ..  This script starts from the top . It will list all of your accounts, then list all the properties, and finally list all the datastreams and their corrosponding measurement id ..  You can disassemble the script any way you see fit (If you KNEW property ID for instance)   I am using PHP here and Google's own `analytics-admin` installed with composer, but you can use raw curl statements and OATH to facilitate the same thing .. The methodology is the same.

```
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Analytics\Admin\V1beta\AnalyticsAdminServiceClient;

putenv("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=" . __DIR__ . '/service-account-credentials.json');
$client = new AnalyticsAdminServiceClient();

$accounts = $client->listAccounts();

foreach ($accounts as $account) {

    $accountName = "parent:" . $account->getName();
    $displayName = $account->getDisplayName();
    $createAccountName = $account->getName();

    echo "\n\nFound account: $displayName | $accountName\n";
    try {

        $response = $client->listProperties($accountName);
        $properties = $response->iterateAllElements(); // Get an iterable of properties
        $propertyCount = iterator_count($properties); // Count the properties
        echo "    Number of properties: $propertyCount\n\n";

        foreach ($response as $property) {

            $propertyId = $property->getName();
            $display_name = $property->getDisplayName();
            echo "$propertyId: $display_name\n";
            
            $propertyDataStreams = $client->listDataStreams($propertyId);
            foreach ($propertyDataStreams as $propertyDataStream) {
                $stream_id = $propertyDataStream->getName() . PHP_EOL;

                $id = $client->getDataStream($stream_id)->getWebStreamData()->getMeasurementId();

                echo "Measurement ID: $id\n\n";
            }
        }

    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        echo "An error occurred: " . $e->getMessage();
    }

}
```

The output of that script (again written in PHP using Googles analytics-admin-api)

```
Found account: BLOCK 1 | parent:accounts/xxxxxxxx
    Number of properties: 100

properties/xxxxx: [REDACTED]
    Measurement ID: G-4HMxxx
properties/xxxxx: [REDACTED]
    Measurement ID: G-2NHxxx
properties/xxxxx: [REDACTED]
    Measurement ID: G-T9Wxxx
```

The trick is getting the:

```
measurement id 
    OF webstream data 
        OF data stream
            OF property
                OF account
```

You can do this without the PHP script of course, but the above method of getting the Measurement ID will be identical in nature.